# Set NSLayoutConstraint Constant in iOS7

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin, nslayoutconstraint

Ok, I have a super weird issue. I have a UIScrollView that I'm using to update the position of a second UIView. So, when you scroll the UIScrollView, the UIView moves as well at a proportional but slower speed. The code is pretty simple.

```
Scroller.Scrolled += delegate {
  if (Scroller.ContentOffset.Y <= 0) {
    filtersTop.Constant = 0;
  } else {
     filtersTop.Constant = -(Scroller.ContentOffset.Y / 2);
  }
}
```

filtersTop is a NSLayoutConstraint. Scroller is the UIScrollView.

The problem is whenever I set filtersTop.Constant to any value derived from Scroller.Content.Y, it resets Scroll.ContentOffset to 0 in iOS7 only. This code works fine in iOS8+. I've tried a dozen variations on this. If I set filtersTop.Constant to a static number (ie: 123.5), that works.

I've tried saving the value to a variable and forcing the type thinking maybe it was getting cast improperly. If I trace out the value, it works. But, the minute I set it to filtersTop.Constant, it resets Scroller.ConstentOffset.Y again. Scroller and filters are NOT related. They are not nested or associated with each other in any way. So, I have no idea why setting the constant on the constraint on filters would in any way affect Scroller.

Anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: Are you able to add a bit more of the class you call this from or how you setup the constraints? I have created a test project with what I think you are trying to achieve here https://github.com/b099l3/SO_TESTING and it seems to run ok on the iOS7.1 simulator and iOS7 device. would you be able to check this out and see if you have set it up similarly?

Comment: Also what version of Xamarion.iOS are you running? I have Xamarin.iOS
Version: 8.10.2.37

Comment: I am using Xamarin.iOS 8.10. I checked the code you posted to GitHub and that is almost exactly what we are trying to accomplish. So, that's good news that it can be done. About the only major difference I can see is that our layout is built entirely through code as opposed to Xib's. We are using MvvmCross for the data model but I uploaded the view so you could take a look. That is posted at http://www.bigclubdigital.com/DirecTV/MoviesView.cs.zip if ou want to take a look. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue your talking about still trying to find a fix for it tho. It is really quite strange

Comment: Whoo hoo. I'm glad i'm not crazy. I've started at that thing for hours now and I cannot see why the ContentOffset would ever get reset. I assumed it must be some fundamental misunderstanding of how constraints are handled through code. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Did you manage to get any further with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I had another look it seems to be resetting the contentSize between calling `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` and calling `ViewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
ContentSize set to: {Width=320, Height=3000}
Called ViewWillLayoutSubviews
ContentSize set to: {Width=320, Height=3000}
ContentSize set to: {Width=0, Height=0}
Called ViewDidLayoutSubviews
```

I then subclassed the scrollview and forced the contentSize to stay the same like so:

```
public class CustomScroller : UIScrollView
{
    public CustomScroller ()
    {
        ContentSize = new CGSize(320,3000);
    }

    public override CGSize ContentSize {
        get {
            return base.ContentSize;//new CGSize(320,3000);
        }
        set {
            base.ContentSize = new CGSize(320,3000);

            Console.WriteLine ("ContentSize set to: "+ContentSize);
        }
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("LayoutSubviews: "+Frame.Y);
        base.LayoutSubviews ();
    }
}
```

You will then have to set the contentSize when the view loads rather than in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews`.

I have updated the code [here](https://github.com/b099l3/SO_TESTING) with the solution detailed above and here is the result. [image: result]

**Note** I changed the scrolled code but it will work with the original too.

This works in iOS7 and iOS8. Hope this helps!